# What does Varchar(2000 char) mean in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle

I need to find a field length for a text field in application. i.e, How many words or characters I can store in that field. Should I need to check it in DB or in code?

Comment: It means a maximum of 2000 characters **or** 4000 bytes (general maximum length), whichever is less. 2000 characters may be more than 4000 bytes if using a multi-byte character set.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , Oracle prefer Varchar2 data type instead of varchar.
secondly, before Oracle 12C, the max length of varchar2 is 4000 in SQL , but in PL/SQL, the max length varchar2 is 32K; since 12C, it is same for SQL and PL/SQL, the max length of varchar2 is 32K.

Comment: There is a small gotcha with the 32K size for varchar2. It is  valid only if `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED`.  This must be set by the DBA when the system is in initialized or in maintenance mode. If  `MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD` (the default)  the max for varchar2 size remains 4000.. Unfortunately it seems most DBAs are cowards and just take the default.